# How to pass a string containing slash ('/') as parameter to a route in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue router and I have a route

```
{ path: '/my-route/:param?', component: MyComponent }
```

I have the link to my route as

```
<router-link :to="'/my-route/'+myParam">Link text</router-link>
```

if `myParam` is a string containing `'/'` like `'abc/def'`, it navigates to the link `/my-route/abc/def` which doesn't exists. How to solve this?

Comment: I need to get param as `abc/def` in my component using `this.$route.params.param` . No problem if url is shown as `/my-route/abc/def`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode the url with javascript function `encodeURIComponent(uri)`

**Update your router-link**

```
<router-link :to="'/my-route/'+encodeURIComponent(myParam)">Link text</router-link>
```